# How to show some menu links only to registered users

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Can anyone help me with displaying a menu in ASP.Net?

I've got my `Site.master` page with a navigation menu

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
   <Items>
      <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
      <asp:LoginView>
         <LoggedInTemplate>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Securedpage.aspx" Text="Securedpage"/>
         </LoggedInTemplate>
      </asp:LoginView>
   </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

I have to show the first menu link to everyone and the second only to loggedIn users. However the `<asp:LoginView>` seems to be unrecognised within the menu block. Is there any way out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the menu items to a site map and use the roles attribute. You will need to enable Security Trimming in your Web.Config to do this. This is the simplest way.

Site Navigation Overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e468hxky.aspx

Security Trimming Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx

SiteMap Binding Info: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_navigation.asp

Good Tutorial/Overview here: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/26/asp-net-menu-and-sitemap-security-trimming-plus-a-trick-for-when-your-menu-and-security-don-t-match-up.aspx

Another option that works, but is less ideal is to use the loginview control which can display controls based on role. This might be the quickest (but least flexible/performant) option. You can find a guide here: http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2010/07/28/role-based-authorization-using-loginview-control.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would choose the code behind approach: only add LoginView item to the Items collection if the user is logged in. With the Membership API you can check this with:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Another impartant this is to secure that page not just hiding in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You may use separate master templates for logged in users and anonymous users. The master template with anonymous users can have only the links which can be viewed by all. And apply the logged in user master template to the page you want to show after login so that the user will geet the expected menus.Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you want to disable menu item for any page.

on masterpage.cs file.

```
public bool UserMenu
{   
    set { Menu1.Visible = value; }
}
```

for the page_load where you want to disable the menu.

```
this.Master.UserMenu = false;
```

Comment: for the other page where u want to disable the menu.(asp.net pages)

Comment: use the below line in aspx page. below the directive path    <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="MasterPageName.master" %>